# ImportError: cannot import name model

Tags: django, importerror

**Hello everyone.**
This is the first time I ask for help on StackOverflow, so please forgive me if my question here is clear enough... I will gladly provide anything you ask me for in order to have a better understanding of this issue

I have Django project that is not importing a model from an app that is registered on my settings.

This app has been working good until 2 day ago, but I haven't made any changes related to models.

I have tried many things to fix this issue but still giving me the same error...
I can't import anything coming from the models on any of my apps...

This is very frustrating.  Please some advise

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # Django Applications
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',

    #    'satchmo_store.shop',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django_comments',
    'django.contrib.humanize',

    # Reorder admin apps
    'admin_reorder',

    # Third Party Django Applications
    ##    'django_extensions',
    'photologue',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'filebrowser',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'snowpenguin.django.recaptcha2',
    'tinymce',
    'django_extensions',
    'model_utils',
    'cart',
    'anymail',
    'rest_framework',

    'storages',
    # 'django_s3_storage',

    'my_project.libs.chunks',    
    'my_project.apps.definition',
    'my_project.apps.makeaword',
    'my_project.apps.tellinstories',
    'my_project.apps.wordsearch',
    'my_project.libs.payflowpro',

    # Project Applications
    'my_project.apps.accounts',
    'my_project.apps.book',
    'my_project.apps.general',
    'my_project.apps.illustrate',
    'my_project.apps.write',
    'my_project.apps.pressroom',
    'my_project.apps.images',
    'my_project.apps.comic',
    'my_project.apps.library',
    'my_project.apps.reports',
    'my_project.apps.orders',
    'my_project.apps.gift_cards',
    'my_project.apps.stationary',
    'my_project.apps.invoices',
    'my_project.apps.cart_itt',
)
```

Comment: How are you importing. You have to show the code.

Comment: Hello Biplove. Thank you in advance for your help...

`from my_project.apps.general.models import GiftCardOrders`

Comment: Edit your post with the information.. Also, add ```Installed_APPS``` from **settings.py**

Comment: Where is your project??

Comment: I added all info at the main question

Answer (score 2):

Import like:

```
from general.models import GiftCardOrders
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I discovered that after identing the file, something went wrong.
Revert all changes made and it worked.